# how to find serial port of my gps device?

Tags: usb, serial-port

in Ubuntu 20.04 lts, I'm using usb gps module. when I plugged, it can change between ttyACM[0..9]. How can I specifically detect usb gps? I used pyusb but it won't show serial port details.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with searching GPS in descriptions on list_ports.

```
from serial.tools import list_ports


def get_port() -> str:
    try:
        for dev in list_ports.comports():
            if 'GPS' in dev.description:
                return dev.device
    except:
        return ''
```